# When did Akedat (Binding of Isaac) Issac occur

Tags: sources-mekorot, binding-of-isaac

I heard that one of the reasons that we read "Akedat Issac" in Rosh Hashana is since it happened at the same day. On the other hand, I heard that it occurred on Yom Kippur (day of Atonement). Are there any sources that support it?